# Method references of listFiles

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have once read the following code from a book about method references.

```
File[] hiddenFiles = new File(".").listFiles(File::isHidden)
```

When I look up from the File API for the `listFiles` method, I see it only has the following methods:

```
listFiles(FileFilter filter)

listFiles(FilenameFilter filter)
```

I have tried the code and it works. But while the API states it accepts either `FileFilter` or `FilenameFilter`, why the code can work ?

My understanding of File::isHidden is that it is equivalent to the following lambdas:

```
(File file) -> file.isHidden()
```

But in FileFilter, the method that need to specify is following.

```
boolean accept(File pathname)
```

Then shouldn't there be a method named accept defined there, like:

```
File[] hiddenFiles = new File(".").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
 public boolean accept(File file) {
   return file.isHidden();
 }
});
```

Or the compiler can somehow automatically detect the pattern and regard the code as a FileFilter, although the method "accept" is not defined and a FileFilter object is not created ?

Comment: Can you explain why you think the code should not work? Do you think that `File::isHidden` is not a `FileFilter`? What do you think it is then?

Comment: I have further supplemented my understanding.

Comment: I never seen FileFIlter before but just looked it up https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html . As you will read, it has method *accept(File)* which returns a *bool* . Notice that *File::isHidden* fits that criteria.

Comment: @sea: I hope your question is resolved. "File::isHidden" works because it is a "method reference", and the Oracle "FileFilter" documentation explicitly says a method reference is OK.  In this context, all three options: 1) an anonymous class implementing [FileFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html), 2) `File::isHidden` method reference, and 3) `(File file) -> file.isHidden()` lambda are equivalent.  Only 1) is possible in Java 7 and earlier.  My [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64408863/421195) below gives more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually several interesting parts to this question:

- Q: What is `isHidden`, and why is it a permissible argument to File.listFiles()?

  > https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-ishidden-method-in-java-with-examples
  >
  > The isHidden() function is a part of File class in Java . This
  > function determines whether the is a file or Directory denoted by the
  > abstract filename is Hidden or not.The function returns true if the
  > abstract file path is Hidden else return false.
- Q: What is the `File::isHidden` syntax?

  The "double colon" is a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).  It's new with Java 8 and higher.
- Q: So why is isHidden() an acceptable FileFilter parameter?

  > https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html
  >
  > This is a functional interface and can therefore be used as the assignment target for a lambda expression or method reference.

  `File::isHidden` is a lambda expression that returns "true" or "false".

Comment: Technically *File::isHidden* is not a lambda expression. It is, however, a method reference.

Comment: As a lambda expression though I believe it would be *(File f) -> f.isHidden()* . I haven't used Java in a while so syntax might not be correct.